# Duplicate symbols found in static library

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

I am dealing with compiling source code for two different modules abc, xyz

abc and xyz share common source files which gets compiled separately. And while creating static library foo.a, i have to include all the object files from abc,xys modules.

Lets say i have a.c file which is common for both abc,xyz modules i am creating object files named abc_a.o , xyz_a.o , Note that underlying source file is same i.e. a.c

Once after i create the obj files i use `ar` tool to create static library foo.a

`ar rcs foo.a *_a.o`

Since i am dealing with huge project, I have thousands of such files exists. I am following the approach of finding md5sum of object files and filter-out duplicate object files just before creating static library. But that is consuming huge build time.

Here is the sample make file snippet:-

```
OBJECT_FILES := kvctmp1934.o kvctmp2160.o kvctmp1932.o kvctmp1931.o kvctmp1939.o .... <may more obj files>

DUPLICATES := $(shell md5sum $(OBJECT_FILES) | sort | uniq -d -w32 | cut -d' ' -f3)

$(info DUPLICATES are $(DUPLICATES))
```

Is there any other better approach for my requirement to find duplicate obj files which got built from same source file?

Comment: The sane thing is of course to refactor `a.c` into a shared dependency of `abc` and `xyz`, so it's compiled only once. Not only does this avoid the expensive `md5sum`, it also saves you an unnecessary compilation.

Comment: Rather than filter out duplicates, it is more common to include only the necessary files for a library to accomplish its task.

Comment: Are you compiling the common files for each module separately because of different conditional compilation for the modules?

Comment: @IanAbbott, yes You are right.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Do we have any other approach w.o going via md5 ?

Comment: @vam It is difficult to propose a specific solution without a [mre]. Show a few example files and a `Makefile` with the rules to build the library and the application(s). Please explain in more detail why you compile `a.c` to `abc_a.o` and `xyz_a.o` instead of `a.o`. Please [edit] your question to add clarification or requested information.

Comment: one approach i could think of is to look for dependency files i.e. .d files which has rules for each .o file with pre-requisites as included header files. But i dont see the rule where .o has .c file as pre-requisit. I am using -MMD,-MP flag. How can I see the rule where `.o : .c` , so that i can grep all .d files and look for the rule to find the duplicate obj files.

Comment: @Bodo, for each different module i have to prefix the module name for obj files for easy identification.

Comment: @vam Please [edit] your question to provide clarification or requested information. Don't use comments for this purpose. Your comment does not explain why you think that you *have to* do this. This approach is the cause of your problems and may even lead to errors if the two objects are different what might happen with conditional compilation. **Please show a [mre].**

Answer (score 1):

The modules in a static library (a `.a` archive) even if they are duplicated, will never be linked twice, as the linker only selects the archive modules that actually solve some unsatisfied references, and will not select them a second time, if they appear to be already linked.  Why? because all the references the object module solves are already solved, and if new references are encountered, the original module that included them will be the one selected to solve, and so, the new one will not be selected again.

If you are getting that error, is because:

- You have included several (different) modules with the same global identifier.
- You have actually specified the same module twice (or more times) in the linker command line.

IMHO, you don't need the pipeline you are using to avoid duplicated modules, just put them in the `.a` archive an the linker will select them only once.  Even if you put the library several times in the command line (you use `-la -la -la...` several times) each module will be linked only once, and the next occurrences will be skipped, as the unsatisfied references are already satisfied)

By the way, it is very important that the archives are linked as libraries (with option `-l`) which is different than specifying a `.a` file in the linking command line.

```
ld ... -la
```

will search a library called `liba.a` and will treat it as a library, linking conditionally the modules included, only if they satisfy some unsatisfied reference.  But if you do, instead:

```
ld ... liba.a
```

then the linker will include ll the modules inside the archive into the binary executable.  This will happen as if you had written all the `.o` files in the command line at the place of the archive.  This is a legacy of old linkers.  You should be careful.